# EmbeddedKafkaBroker Error with EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:71

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

We used **KafkaEmbedded** with **spring-kafka-test 2.1.4.RELEASE** earlier.

While upgrading **spring-kafka-test to 2.4.13.RELEASE**, we required to move from KafkaEmbedded to **EmbeddedKafkaBroker**. This is giving below error. We are using EmbeddedKafka annotation and spring boot starter parent version is 2.0.0.RELEASE, spring-kafka version is 2.1.4.RELEASE.

Tried different versions of spring-kafka-test.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor 
  at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.<clinit>(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:92)
  at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:71)
  at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:336)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:366)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
  at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
  at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
  at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
  at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
  at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  37 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your versions are mis-matched. Boot 2.0.x and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.4.x are no longer supported, but 2.4.x requires Boot 2.2.x or later. See the matrix on the project page:

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview

Also see

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

and

https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

The current (OSS) supported Boot versions are 2.7.x and 3.0.x, and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.9.x and 3.0.x.

You also must use the same version for `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test`; they cannot be different.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your Guidance Gary, After moving to 2.3.4 for all spring-boot-starter-parent, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test. I am getting below error.                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenSeq
 at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala)
 at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:615)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenSeq
 at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenSeq

Comment: Why 2.3.4? The last 2.3.x version was 2.3.12 - also see that matrix; boot 2.3 requires SK 2.5.x or 2.6.x - in any case, all those versions are out of support. Again; all versions must match according to that table. This error is probably because the kafka version is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, Now i followed the table, move the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.3.12.RELEASE and 2.5.17.RELEASE for spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.utils.Logging.$init$(Lkafka/utils/Logging;)V. Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.utils.Logging.$init$(Lkafka/utils/Logging;)V
 at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<init>(TestUtils.scala:79)at EmbeddedZookeeper.(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:738)

Comment: Now you have the wrong kafka version (kafka-clients as well as the kafka jars for the embedded broker). If you are using Spring Boot, it will bring in all the right versions, if you specify your own version, it must be the same for all `kafka*` jars - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.17.RELEASE/reference/html/#update-deps